# Class variables used outside class ActionScript 3.0  - AS3 Getters and Setters

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, flash-cs5

I wrote a class which contains a few variabes:

```
public class myButton extends Sprite{
    private var button:Sprite = new Sprite();
    public var Colors:Array;
    public var gType:String = GradientType.LINEAR;
    public var mRotate:Number = 0;
    ...
}
```

I want to edit this variables in main file like that:

```
var btn:myButton = new myButton();
btn.Colors = [0xFFFFFF, 0xFFFF00];
btn.mRotate = Math.PI/2;
```

The sciript is running but it doesnt see the changing of these variables. I think that its a easy problem but I cant solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want are setter and getter functions inside your class:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method#Actionscript_3.0_example

Then, in every setter you need to actually do something when the variable changes.

Try this

```
public class myButton extends Sprite{
    //....
    //note the change to private, common practice is to use lowercase first names in vars 
    //and include _ in front of private vars 
    private var _colors:Array;
    private var _mRotate:Number = 0;
    //...

    //getter and setter for _colors
    public function set colors(value:Array):void{
          _colors = value;
          var ct:ColorTransform = this.transform.colorTransform;
          ct.color = _colors[0]; //for simplicity I use only 1 color
          this.transform.colorTransform = ct;
    }

    public function get colors():Array{
         return _colors;
    }

    //do the same for mRotate but use the Number type

}
```

This will allow you to do

```
 var btn:MyBtn = new MyBtn();
 btn.colors = [...];
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no reason why modifying public variables wouldn't work (even though you should't do it). It sounds more like your update loop isn't doing what you're expecting?

If I paste your code and do the following, it acts as expected:

Code:

```
import MyButton;
var btn = new MyButton();
trace(">> mRotate: " + btn.mRotate); 
btn.mRotate = 5;
trace(">> mRotate: " + btn.mRotate);
```

Output:

```
>> mRotate: 0
>> mRotate: 5
```

But again, you really shouldn't be declaring your variables public and access them directly.